# How do I combine these tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My goal is to have a 5 by 5 table that looks like this:

| State | MostRE | MostNRE | LeastRE | LeastNRE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WA | 4499698 | blank | blank | blank |
| TX | blank | 91590135 | blank | blank |
| DC | blank | blank | 4780 | blank |
| DC | blank | blank | blank | 438130 |

I have found the queries separately:

```
select re.state, max(TotalrenewableE) as Most_RE
from #temp_RE as re
Inner join(
select max(TotalRenewableE) TotalRE
from #temp_RE)MaxTRE
On MaxTRE.TotalRE = RE.TotalRenewableE
Group by re.state 


select nre.state, max(TotalNonrenewableE) as Most_NRE
from #temp_NonRE as nre
Inner join(
select max(totalnonrenewablee) TotalNRE
from #temp_NonRE)MaxTNRE
On MaxTNRE.TotalNRE = NRE.TotalNonrenewableE
Group by nre.state



select re.state, min(TotalrenewableE) as Least_RE
from #temp_RE as re
Inner join(
select min(TotalRenewableE) TotalRE
from #temp_RE)MinTRE
On MinTRE.TotalRE = RE.TotalRenewableE
Group by re.state 



select nre.state, min(TotalNonrenewableE) as Least_NRE
from #temp_NonRE as nre
Inner join(
select min(totalnonrenewablee) TotalNRE
from #temp_NonRE)MinTNRE
On MinTNRE.TotalNRE = NRE.TotalNonrenewableE
Group by nre.state
```

I have tried:

```
select nre.state, 
min(TotalNonrenewableE) as Least_NRE,
min(TotalRenewableE) as Least_RE,
max(TotalNonrenewableE) as Most_NRE, 
max(TotalRenewableE) as Most_RE,
from #temp_NonRE as nre, #temp_RE as re
Inner Join(
select min(totalnonrenewablee) TotalNRE
from #temp_NonRE)MinTNRE
On MinTNRE.TotalNRE = #temp_NonRE.TotalNonrenewableE
Inner Join(
select min(TotalRenewableE) TotalRE
from #temp_RE)MinTRE
On MinTRE.TotalRE = RE.TotalRenewableE
Inner Join(
select max(totalnonrenewablee) TotalNRE
from #temp_NonRE)MaxTNRE
On MaxTNRE.TotalNRE = #temp_NonRE.TotalNonrenewableE
Inner Join(
select max(TotalRenewableE) TotalRE
from #temp_RE)MaxTRE
On MaxTRE.TotalRE = RE.TotalRenewableE
Where nre.State = re.State
Group by nre.state
```

But it gives me this error:

> The multi-part identifier "#temp_NonRE.TotalNonrenewableE" could not be bound.

I just cant figure out how to combine them to make the table above.

Thank you for the hard work

Comment: you dont happen to know which line is causing the error do you?

Comment: `MinTNRE.TotalNRE = #temp_NonRE.TotalNonrenewableE`, you gave the temp table an alias, so it is now only to be referred to by that alias. You do this for the other temp table, so I'm voting to close as typo

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use comma separated join syntax, but use `join...on`. And you *definitely* shouldn't mix the two forms

Comment: I do not know where the error is coming from.  I think it is coming from the fact that each row is not filling each column but I do not know how to say if no value then blank.  but again I am not sure if that is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union all and group once again

```
select state, max(Most_RE) Most_RE, max(Most_NRE) Most_NRE, max(LeastRE) LeastRE, max(LeastNRE) LeastNRE  
from (
    select re.state, max(TotalrenewableE) as Most_RE, null Most_NRE, null LeastRE, null LeastNRE
    from #temp_RE as re
    Inner join(
    select max(TotalRenewableE) TotalRE
    from #temp_RE)MaxTRE
    On MaxTRE.TotalRE = RE.TotalRenewableE
    Group by re.state 
    
    union all
    
    select nre.state, null, max(TotalNonrenewableE) as Most_NRE, null, null
    from #temp_NonRE as nre
    Inner join(
    select max(totalnonrenewablee) TotalNRE
    from #temp_NonRE)MaxTNRE
    On MaxTNRE.TotalNRE = NRE.TotalNonrenewableE
    Group by nre.state
    
    ...
)
group by state
```

Comment: This worked with some minor changes;  add #temp_RE as re in first from, name subquery as x.  add the where x.state = re.state